# Relationship between disjuncts of $a,b$ when $(a \rightarrow b)$ is tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

> What is the relationship between the disjuncts of formulae $a,b$ ( in DNF) when $ \neg a$ is not a tautology and $(a \rightarrow b)$ is a tautology?

Say (up to logical equivalence) $ a= a_1 \vee a_2 ... \vee a_n$ and $b= b_1 \vee ... \vee b_m$ for conjunctive clauses $a_1,... ,a_n,b_1,...,b_m$.
Then a bit of calculation gives $\forall i \leq n \exists j\leq m \ (a_i \rightarrow b_j)$, which isn't particularly enlightening to me. So I am wondering if there is something better one could say. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: If the only letters appearing in $a$ or $b$ are $p_1,\dots, p_N$ then write $a$ and $b$ in full DNF [ie disjunctions of conjunctions of the form $(q_1\wedge\dots\wedge q_N)$ where each $q_i$ is either $p_i$ or $\neg p_i$]. Then $a\to b$ is a tautology if and only if every disjunct of $a$ is a disjunct of $b$.

Comment: If $a \to b$ is a tautology, then also $\lnot a \lor b$ is